# Connecting with MongoDB on different system using PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have MongoDB working on my MacBook and I am using it in the flask app to save my form data.
Now I also have a windows 10 system in my lab at the institution and I can connect to it via VPN and now I want to run my flask app on my mac and save the form data on that windows 10 system.
I am using pymongo for connection.

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.user_login_system
```

I tried changing the 'localhost' to the windows 10 system IP but it didn't work.
Is there any way to connect to the windows 10 MongoDB from my mac using pymongo?

Comment: Please include the error / exception message in full.

Comment: @BellyBuster I actually want to sync the database from my system(mac) to other system(windows) in the same network.

Comment: so in mongo compass under connection string I am passing mongodb://xxx.xx.xx.xx/ and then on clicking connect I am getting connect ECONNREFUSED

Answer (score 0):

By default [MongoDB only allows connections from the local machine](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6/#default-bind-to-localhost); you can widen access in the mongod.conf file.

On your windows machine, edit your /bin/mongod.cfg file and set the `net` section to:

```
net:
   bindIpAll: true
   port: 27017
```

and then restart the MongoDB service, then try it again.

References:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net-options
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp

Comment: I have actually set bindip to 0.0.0.0 and also have mentioned other ips separated them with a comma but still not working :(

Comment: I tried bindIpAll: true but I am getting Error: couldn't connect to server xx.xx.x.xxx:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to xx.xx.x.xxx:27017 :: caused by :: Operation timed out :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
If your time permits could you please look into this and let me know if there is a way around it, Thanks!

Comment: Did you restart the service after changing he values?

Comment: Yes, I restarted service on both systems but it didn't work. Isn't there any other way?